# Xelatex does not work

Tags: xetex, installing

Is it essential to install latex via virtual drive?   I cannot install by virtual drive, because after installation some packages, the following error appears every time:

[image]

I install the latex by this way: I extract the iso file then right click on the “install-tl-windows” and open  that (or run by administrator).  It installs the latex and pdflatex works without any problem. But the xelatex does not work. I tried this way (without virtual drive)  more than 15 times in the last month, for the latex 2021 and 2013 and 2019 and even on the several version of windows 7 (after changing the windows of my laptop), but even one time, xelatex did not work in both texworks and texstudio. Also if I type xelatex in command prompt, the following error appears:

[image]

(of course sometimes the above error appears in the near of the end of latex installation, but I press the okay and installation continue then the message “welcome. . .” appears ).

I think the problem is not related to the windows, because I changed the windows several times.

This is very odd for me. I do not know what to do? And am very disappointed.  Does someone have any idea?

Comment: your problem is not at all clear, I assume you are installing texlive from here? https://tug.org/texlive/, perhaps do a network install of texlive 2022 following the instructions from here https://tug.org/texlive/windows.html#install

Comment: Thank you    .  .  .